# OpenGL - Image == null when tryint to convert byte array to BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, opengl, byte, jogl

I am trying to get the screen using `glReadPixels()` then converting that into an image.
I get an error saying image == null.

```
ByteBuffer _frame = ByteBuffer.allocate( 4 * Main.gui.glCanvas.getWidth() * Main.gui.glCanvas.getHeight() );
    System.out.println( "Num Pixels " + Main.width * Main.height );
    gl.glReadPixels(
            0,
            0,
            Main.gui.glCanvas.getWidth(),
            Main.gui.glCanvas.getHeight(),
            GL3.GL_RGBA,
            GL3.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            _frame
            );

    try {
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read( new ByteArrayInputStream( _frame.array() ) );
        ImageIO.write( bi, "png", new File( "Slices/slicu.png" ) );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() + " @ Filler.draw()" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather use [com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers.newDirectByteBuffer()](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/gluegen/javadoc/com/jogamp/common/nio/Buffers.html#newDirectByteBuffer%28int%29) instead of ByteBuffer.allocate(). If you use an undirect NIO buffer here, JOGL will have to make a direct NIO buffer under the hood and you can't be sure that a NIO buffer is backed by an array anyway, it can be null. Then, create an array and copy the content of your buffer into it.

You could use [com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt.Screenshot](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/awt/Screenshot.html), [com.jogamp.opengl.util.GLReadBufferUtil](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/GLReadBufferUtil.html) or [com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt.AWTGLReadBufferUtil](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/awt/AWTGLReadBufferUtil.html) instead, there are some examples on Github in jogl-demos.

I advise you to ask your questions about JOGL rather on [our official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org).